# YAML custom tags in Go

Tags: go, yaml, tags, marshalling

I have these nested structs in Go with custom tags for their properties,

```
type DummyParams struct {
  Param1 string `yaml:"param1"`
  Param2 string `yaml:"param2"`
}

type Dummy struct {
  Name string `yaml:"name"`
  Type string `yaml:"type"`
  Params DummyParams `yaml:"params"`
}
```

I create some instances of Dummy and add them to a slice,

```golang
dummies := make([]Dummy, 0)
dummy1 := Dummy {
    Name: "a"
    Type: "type a"
    Params: DummyParams {
        Param1: "foo"
        Param2: "bar"
    }
}
dummies = append(dummies, dummy1)
dummy2 := Dummy {
    Name: "b"
    Type: "type b"
    Params: DummyParams {
        Param1: "foo"
        Param2: "bar"
    }
}
dummies = append(dummies, dummy2)
```

Finally I marshal the data and write it to file

```golang
yamlData, err := yaml.Marshal(&dummies)
// handle error ...
writeErr := os.WriteFile("foo.yaml", yamlData, 0644)
// handle write error ...
```

But the yaml I am getting does not have the lower case tagged names, instead it has the upper case Struct names.
Anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Which yaml marshaler are you using?

Comment: Oh forgot the ".", I am using the one in the yaml library https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/yaml@v1.3.0

Comment: Blame it on the yaml implementation you're using. If you use `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` for example, it works. Try it on the Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/mySPFO4xtTe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blame it on the yaml implementation you're using. If you use [`gopkg.in/yaml.v3`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3) for example, it works. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/mySPFO4xtTe). So one solution is to use another YAML implementation, such as `gopkg.in/yaml.v3`.

You mentioned in the comments that you're using https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/yaml@v1.3.0. Its package doc says:

> In short, this library first converts YAML to JSON using go-yaml and then uses `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal` to convert to or from the struct. This means that it effectively reuses the JSON struct tags as well as the custom JSON methods `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` unlike go-yaml.

So `sigs.k8s.io/yaml@v1.3.0` first marshals to JSON. If you want lowercased field names, use `json` tags instead of `yaml` tags:

```
import "sigs.k8s.io/yaml"

type DummyParams struct {
    Param1 string `json:"param1"`
    Param2 string `json:"param2"`
}

type Dummy struct {
    Name   string      `json:"name"`
    Type   string      `json:"type"`
    Params DummyParams `json:"params"`
}
```

With this change output contains lowercased names (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/bJVgd52_2oP)):

```
- name: a
  params:
    param1: foo
    param2: bar
  type: type a
- name: b
  params:
    param1: foo
    param2: bar
  type: type b
```

Note that having to use `json` tags instead of `yaml` to make it work is just a quirk of the `sigs.k8s.io/yaml@v1.3.0` package. If you want to make it work with *this* package and other yaml implementations, you may provide *both* `json` and `yaml` tags:

```
type DummyParams struct {
    Param1 string `json:"param1" yaml:"param1"`
    Param2 string `json:"param2" yaml:"param2"`
}

type Dummy struct {
    Name   string      `json:"name" yaml:"name"`
    Type   string      `json:"type" yaml:"type"`
    Params DummyParams `json:"params" yaml:"params"`
}
```